# Replace text in csv without uppercase and spaces

Tags: batch-file

this script replaces a bit of text within a scv with the filename of the csv.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
    set "line=%%f"
    set "line=!line:REPLACE=%%~ni!"
    echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
endlocal
```

So say the file was called `CSV File`. The text would be replaced with `"CSV File"`. My question is how do i format that text with no spaces or uppercase letters?
So my files called `"CSV File"`, but the replacement is `"csv-file"`. I've tried to strip out the spaces first so I've tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
    ::Tried to strip out the spaces from %%~ni
    set %%~ni=%%%~ni: =%

    set "line=%%f"
    set "line=!line:REPLACE=%%~ni!"
    echo(!line!

)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
endlocal
```

Doesn't work with that, anyone know why? I did get this working:

```
    set "line=!line: =-!"
```

But I can't do that as it'll effect the whole csv. So I'm not sure if there's a way to tell that line to just effect the replacment text?

Edited code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
        set "line=%%f"
        echo %%~ni

        set MyVar=%%~ni
        set MyVar=!MyVar: =-!
        set MyVar=!MyVar:,=!
        echo !MyVar!

        set "line=!line:REPLACE=!MyVar!!"
        echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
```

I've managed to strip out the spaces and a comma, so just working on how to get that `!MyVar!` in my replacement.

Comment: You can convert to lower/upper case with batch, but you'll have to change everey possible single character, IMO a bit tedious. Choose a helper script/tool to achieve this.

Comment: I did read that, but I maybe able to get it working by just replacing the spaces with "-". Is there an easy way to do that? I've already done that in my script I just wont know how to get it to effect just the variable I want, it's affecting all the csv.

Comment: `for %%c in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "line=!line:%%c=%%c!"` converts to lower-case (since sub-string substitution is case-insensitive), given that there are no higher characters like `Å`, `î`, `ó`, etc...

Comment: That looks more like what I was after, thanks for that. I've put some edited code above. It's still replacing the string but it's not lowercase. Have I implemented that wrong? And the string im replacing, and replacing it with contains nothing but A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ It's the `%%~ni` I'm needing lowercase and without spaces.

Comment: `%%~ni` needs to be safe for a web url, is basically what I'm trying to say, so it needs to be stripped of all special characters and no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use powershell as a tool for this.

From cmdline:

```
> type "TEST FILE.CSV"
One,two,three
bla,REPLACE,blubb
REPLACE,test,blah
tralala,blah,REPLACE

> for /f "delims=" %A in ('Dir /B/S "test*.csv"') do @powershell -Nop -c "(Get-Content '%~fA') -Replace 'REPLACE',('%~nxA').Replace(' ','-').ToLower()|Set-Content '%~fA'"

> type "TEST FILE.CSV"
One,two,three
bla,test-file.csv,blubb
test-file.csv,test,blah
tralala,blah,test-file.csv
```

In a batch file double the `%`-signs

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'Dir /B/S "test*.csv"'
) do powershell -Nop -c "(Get-Content '%%~fA') -Replace 'REPLACE',('%%~nxA').Replace(' ','-').ToLower()|Set-Content '%%~fA'"
```

Comment: I've never used powershell to be perfectly honest. Can I use this within my batch file? I'm honestly not sure how to use this within my file. Is it just the `for` line I need?

Comment: Yes, as I said use it as a tool. Every halfway actual windows version has powershell included, the syntax used should work even with PSv2 coming with Windows 7.